# SSIS Script Task Connect to DB2/MVS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, db2

I have a script task that needs to connect to both DB2 on LUW and DB2 on Z/OS.  My understanding is that within the script task I should use an ADO.NET Connection manager.
This I have done for the DB2 on LUW connection using the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 and can connect just fine.  Using that as a guide I am trying to create a connection manager for DB2 mainframe, almost identical except for server name / port number and DBMS platform properties.  I've tried every which way to get a connection to Db2 on Z/OS and wind up with an error "Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.  The request for the host resource failed."

I can define an OLEDB connection manager and connect via its "test connection" but cannot use in script task.

Any thoughtss most welcome,

Phil Jackson

Comment: In order to connect to DB2 on z/OS or DB2 i you need an additional product, DB2 Connect, in addition to the typical IBM Data Server Client package. Do you have DB2 Connect installed and properly configured?

Comment: Yes we do.  I can define OLEDB connection managers using the IBMDADB2 provider or ADO.NET providers using the IBMDADB2 provider or even the DB2ODBC provider and connect via the connection manager "test connection" interface, but not the ADO.NET DB2OLEDB provider.  None of the other providers will work from within the script task..

Comment: Running this in 32 bit mode? While it was cantankerous to deal with DB2 Connect, we had no issues working with DB2 on z/OS.